# Regex: Using smatch on a non-const string

Tags: c++, regex, string

I have the following MWE, which looks for two words in a constant string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    const std::string str = " \"car\":\"1\", \"boats\":2, \"three\":3, \"two\":22 ";

    const std::regex rgx("\"car\"|\"boat\"");
    std::smatch match;

    std::cout << (std::regex_search(str.begin(), str.end(), match, rgx)) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

This works as intended, however, in my case I'm not dealing with constant strings, but variable strings. It seems though that the above only works for constant strings. Is it possible to make a version that doesn't require const str?

Comment: Can you show us what your problem is with code? As in, show us the not-working version.

Comment: [OT]: Raw string can make string nicer: `R"( "car":"1", "boats":2, "three":3, "two":22 )"`.

Comment: @AndyG Remove `const` in `const std::string str` results in errors when compiling.

Comment: You may just use `regex_search(s, matches, r)` where `s` is `std::string`, `matches` is `std::smatch` and `r` is an `std::regex` ([demo](https://ideone.com/PMyi99)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that [`smatch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results) implies that the Bidirectional iterator type used for [`regex_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) is a `std::string::const_iterator`:

Basically it's an alias that looks like this:

```
using std::smatch = std::match_results<std::string::const_iterator>;
```

So when you call `regex_search` with a non-const iterator `begin()` and `end()` it fails to deduce the proper overload.

You can get around this a few ways:

- use `cbegin()` and `cend()` like [P0W](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47138724/27678) suggested:
- use `str` by itself: `regex_search(str, match, rgx)`
- avoid `smatch`:

(Use `match_results` manually)

```
std::match_results<std::string::iterator> match;
std::cout << (std::regex_search(str.begin(), str.end(), match, rgx)) << "\n";
```

Comment: Nice and detailed answer

Answer (score 2):

With non const `std::string` you can simple use :

```
std::regex_search (str.cbegin(), str.cend(), match, rgx) )
                       ~~            ~~
```